# ruby helpers to create views' text around associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, helper

I am not sure what this is called, but I have a model a which has_many b. When showing some model a in a view, I would like to print some text describing all the model b associations it has like the following:

"Has an association with foo, bar, baz, and ## more..."

foo, bar, baz are names of three mobdel b's. And I don't want to print all the names if there are more than 3, so I want to trail it off with the balance # of associations remaining.

I can do this programatically in ruby, but I was wondering if some helper methods exists which can do this for me..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version with range checking + optional block to convert items to string:

```
def enumerate_as_text(seq, max, &block)
  text = seq.first(max).map { |itm|
    block_given? ? yield(itm) : itm.to_s
  }.join(", ")
  text += ", and #{seq.length - max} more" if max < seq.length
  text
end
```

Test run:

```
blob = %w{a b c d e f g h i j}

puts blob.length
puts blob.join(", ")
puts enumerate_as_text(blob, 1)
puts enumerate_as_text(blob, 4)
puts enumerate_as_text(blob, 9)
puts enumerate_as_text(blob, 10)
puts enumerate_as_text(blob, 11)
puts enumerate_as_text(blob, 20) { |itm| "itm: #{itm}" }
```

Output:

```
10
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j
a, and 9 more
a, b, c, d, and 6 more
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, and 1 more
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j
itm: a, itm: b, itm: c, itm: d, itm: e, itm: f, itm: g, itm: h, itm: i, itm: j
```

Comment: it doesn't answer the question: how could he get automatically the associations?

Comment: Part of the answer should have been to use `reflect_on_all_associations`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do that easily, and the ruby / rails code to get it is pretty simple. So why not doing a helper method on your own? The signature for your method could be:

```
def truncate_models(models, numbers)
  models[0..numbers-1].map{|m| m.name}.join(", ") + "and #{models.size - numbers} more..."
end
```

So by calling (in a HAML way)

```
.models
  Has an association with
  = truncate_models(models, 3)
```

you should get what you want.

Comment: it doesn't answer the question: how could he get automatically the associations?

Comment: Part of the answer should have been to use `reflect_on_all_associations`

Comment: @apneadiving, as I read the question, dhruvg knows that the three or more things things are all of class B, "model a has_many b". dhruvg is not looking for all the associations of all types and therefore doesn't need to `reflect_on_all_associations`. That's the answer to a question which isn't being asked.

Comment: @Ray Baxter: IMHO I think he wants to get back what is inside the model. Anyway, let the asker speak: I haven't put any -1.